# Error filling print... Error evaluating expression

Tags: jasper-reports

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="null" language="groovy" pageWidth="555" pageHeight="802" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="478ce75d-1606-47d2-88eb-f8079f50c69b">
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["D:\\newpackage\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_SUB" class="java.lang.Integer" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[Integer.parseInt($P{MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_MAIN})]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_MAIN" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE atr = $P{MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_SUB}]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="national_id_number" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="national_pin_number" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="contact_email" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="biometric_member_number" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <title>
        <band height="74" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="72" uuid="2cee9cb2-abe3-4739-9b64-ec405bf9912b"/>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["D:\\DOCUMENTS\\NetBeansProjects\\NhifHeader\\src\\nhifheader\\PotraitNhifHeader\\PortraitNhifHeader.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="56" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="529" y="13" width="26" height="15" uuid="1d23b617-b659-4f87-acfd-e07b54913ccd"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{national_pin_number}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="367" y="13" width="173" height="15" uuid="e02099fe-b171-4a24-bb15-195a046921c8"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Personal Identification Number:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="1" width="240" height="30" uuid="311343bc-7e09-4658-8a1e-810fe91d1a3f"/>
                <jr:Code39 xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" textPosition="bottom">
                    <jr:codeExpression><![CDATA[$F{biometric_member_number}]]></jr:codeExpression>
                </jr:Code39>
            </componentElement>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="367" y="0" width="31" height="15" uuid="fefca1d6-a90f-4dba-996c-1c00883eba1c"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Date]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="MMMMM dd, yyyy">
                <reportElement x="398" y="0" width="142" height="20" uuid="c3c68a84-f1d6-43c9-9c83-8b5eaacd6c38"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="33" width="555" height="1" forecolor="#E6DAC3" backcolor="#E6DAC3" uuid="003310a9-85b0-447a-bc29-8f97f0006c1d"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="2" y="35" width="553" height="20" uuid="5d8caf66-df88-403d-b96a-1ba2d0e84087"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <text><![CDATA[This is to certify that person shown herein is a member of NHIF: National Hospital Insurance Fund]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="179" y="1" width="172" height="21" forecolor="#C0C0C0" backcolor="#C0C0C0" uuid="63309c64-53a9-41e7-b490-fa5278230357"/>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="33" y="0" width="113" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#000000" uuid="ca2b9d0e-5260-4fb3-9f20-308a4349852e"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Member Certificate]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="67" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="66" uuid="27c682e0-71b6-4232-8a7a-9efaad62240f"/>
                <subreportParameter name="MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_MAIN">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_MAIN}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_SUB">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_SUB}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["D:\\MemberCertificate\\MemberCertificateAddress.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
        <band height="68">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="67" uuid="169130d8-125e-45c4-b455-4cdced7665d1"/>
                <subreportParameter name="MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_MAIN">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_MAIN}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_SUB">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_SUB}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["D:\\MemberCertificate\\MemberCertificateInfo.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
        <band height="56">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="55" uuid="f36d8a91-96b9-44fc-a393-bbc5752b5316"/>
                <subreportParameter name="MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_MAIN">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_MAIN}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_SUB">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_SUB}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["D:\\MemberCertificate\\MemberCertificateIsuranceObligation.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

I  have a JasperReports's report with several subreports. I'm using iReport plugin with my NetBeans. I have passed the same integer parameter type to all sub reports and also to main report . Main report has two parameter , one that has prompt option enabled and is of type string. and the other that takes parameter as a string and coverts it to integer `Integer.parseInt($P{MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_MAIN})` ( this is found in all sub reports  ). This is how i always pass parameters. But when i run this report i get the following errors.

> Error filling print... Error evaluating expression : 
>       Source text : Integer.parseInt($P{MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_MAIN})  net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression : 
>       Source text : Integer.parseInt($P{MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_MAIN})      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:244) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:591) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:559) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setFillParameterValues(JRFillDataset.java:994) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setParameterValues(JRFillDataset.java:635) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.setParameters(JRBaseFiller.java:1280) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:900) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:845) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:87) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:276) 
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:745) 
>       at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:891) 
>       at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1443) 
>       at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:68) 
>       at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:303)      at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2058) 
>   Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null 
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)      at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)

Comment: Just an idea. Does it help if you declare `<parameter name="MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_MAIN"` before `<parameter name="MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_SUB"`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you declared

```
<parameter name="MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_SUB"...>
```

with default value

```
<defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[Integer.parseInt($P{MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_MAIN})]]></defaultValueExpression>
```

before even declaring what `$P{MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_MAIN}` is. It turns out that file is being read from the beginning and all expressions are evaluating at the time they are read. At time of evaluating `"MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_SUB"` report didn't know what `$P{MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_MAIN}` is.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="null" language="groovy" pageWidth="555" pageHeight="802" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" uuid="478ce75d-1606-47d2-88eb-f8079f50c69b">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["D:\\DOCUMENTS\\NetBeansProjects\\BranchHeader\\src\\PortraitBranchHeader\\newpackage\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_MAIN" class="java.lang.String">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_SUB" class="java.lang.Integer" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[Integer.parseInt($P{MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_MAIN})]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT npi.national_id_number, npi.national_pin_number, npi.contact_email, npi.biometric_member_number
FROM (SELECT snpi.nhif_persons_identity_serial, snpi.person_identity_number, snpi.biometric_member_number,
      snpi.national_id_number, snpi.national_pin_number, snpi.national_nhif_number, snpi.address_physical,
      snpi.contact_address, snpi.contact_telephone, snpi.contact_mobile, snpi.address_district, snpi.marital_status,
      snpi.gender, snpi.first_name, snpi.middle_name, snpi.last_name, snpi.date_registered, snpi.contact_email
    FROM nhif_persons_identities snpi
    WHERE snpi.nhif_persons_identity_serial = $P{MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_SUB}) npi]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="national_id_number" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="national_pin_number" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="contact_email" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="biometric_member_number" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="74" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="72" uuid="2cee9cb2-abe3-4739-9b64-ec405bf9912b"/>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["D:\\DOCUMENTS\\NetBeansProjects\\NhifHeader\\src\\nhifheader\\PotraitNhifHeader\\PortraitNhifHeader.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="56" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="529" y="13" width="26" height="15" uuid="1d23b617-b659-4f87-acfd-e07b54913ccd"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{national_pin_number}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="367" y="13" width="173" height="15" uuid="e02099fe-b171-4a24-bb15-195a046921c8"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Personal Identification Number:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="1" width="240" height="30" uuid="311343bc-7e09-4658-8a1e-810fe91d1a3f"/>
                <jr:Code39 xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" textPosition="bottom">
                    <jr:codeExpression><![CDATA[$F{biometric_member_number}]]></jr:codeExpression>
                </jr:Code39>
            </componentElement>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="367" y="0" width="31" height="15" uuid="fefca1d6-a90f-4dba-996c-1c00883eba1c"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Date]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="MMMMM dd, yyyy">
                <reportElement x="398" y="0" width="142" height="20" uuid="c3c68a84-f1d6-43c9-9c83-8b5eaacd6c38"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[new java.util.Date()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="33" width="555" height="1" forecolor="#E6DAC3" backcolor="#E6DAC3" uuid="003310a9-85b0-447a-bc29-8f97f0006c1d"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="2" y="35" width="553" height="20" uuid="5d8caf66-df88-403d-b96a-1ba2d0e84087"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                <text><![CDATA[This is to certify that person shown herein is a member of NHIF: National Hospital Insurance Fund]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="179" y="1" width="172" height="21" forecolor="#C0C0C0" backcolor="#C0C0C0" uuid="63309c64-53a9-41e7-b490-fa5278230357"/>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="33" y="0" width="113" height="20" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#000000" uuid="ca2b9d0e-5260-4fb3-9f20-308a4349852e"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Member Certificate]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="67" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="66" uuid="27c682e0-71b6-4232-8a7a-9efaad62240f"/>
                <subreportParameter name="MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_MAIN">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_MAIN}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_SUB">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_SUB}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["D:\\DOCUMENTS\\NetBeansProjects\\MemberCertificate11212017\\src\\MemberCertificate\\MemberCertificateAddress.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
        <band height="68">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="67" uuid="169130d8-125e-45c4-b455-4cdced7665d1"/>
                <subreportParameter name="MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_MAIN">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_MAIN}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_SUB">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_SUB}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["D:\\DOCUMENTS\\NetBeansProjects\\MemberCertificate11212017\\src\\MemberCertificate\\MemberCertificateInfo.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
        <band height="56">
            <subreport>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="55" uuid="f36d8a91-96b9-44fc-a393-bbc5752b5316"/>
                <subreportParameter name="MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_MAIN">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_MAIN}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_SUB">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{MEMBER_CERTIFICATE_PARAM_SUB}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportParameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_DIR}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <connectionExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></connectionExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["D:\\DOCUMENTS\\NetBeansProjects\\MemberCertificate11212017\\src\\MemberCertificate\\MemberCertificateIsuranceObligation.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch">
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="0" y="18" width="555" height="20" forecolor="#E6DAC3" backcolor="#E6DAC3" uuid="7f256e6e-c72d-4b8b-ad82-acb84e711f34"/>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="3" y="1" width="59" height="19" uuid="209e1c39-a38d-4b3a-a095-95662b9707e5"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="10" isBold="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Disclaimer :]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="62" y="1" width="493" height="19" uuid="3465db13-94ed-4a12-bb82-96732d370a8a"/>
                    <textElement>
                        <font size="10" isBold="false"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[This is an auto generated Certificate and does not require signature]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Egan Wolf Idea works perfect. I just declared the main report parameter before sub report parameter!

Comment: No need to make a copy of right answer. Is it better just to accept right answer (by Egan Wolf)